# EXC_BAD_ACCESS > KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: ios, iphone

My iPhone app crashed and I got the following stack trace from Crashlytics (iPhone 5C, iOS 7.1.1). It continues on for 500+ lines and I don't see anything that references my code anywhere. Is there any way I can debug this?

> Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x04fccfe0
>
> 1. libsystem_c.dylib __vfprintf + 29
> 2. libsystem_c.dylib __v2printf + 374
> 3. libsystem_c.dylib __v2printf + 374
> 4. libsystem_c.dylib _vsnprintf + 348
> 5. libsystem_c.dylib vsnprintf + 72
> 6. libsystem_c.dylib __snprintf_chk + 22
> 7. Foundation _writeJSONNumber + 1040
> 8. Foundation _writeJSONValue + 452
> 9. Foundation ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 100
> 10. CoreFoundation__53-[__NSArrayM
>        enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
> 11. CoreFoundation
>        -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232
> 12. Foundation
>            _writeJSONArray + 236
> 13. Foundation
>        _writeJSONValue + 504
> 14. Foundation
>        ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 100
> 15. CoreFoundation
>        __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
> 16. CoreFoundation
>        -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232
> 17. Foundation
>        _writeJSONArray + 236
> 18. Foundation
>        _writeJSONValue + 504
> 19. Foundation
>        ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 100
> 20. CoreFoundation
>        __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
> 21. CoreFoundation
>        -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232
> 22. Foundation
>        _writeJSONArray + 236
> 23. Foundation
>        _writeJSONValue + 504
> 24. Foundation
>        ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 100
> 25. CoreFoundation
>        __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
> 26. CoreFoundation
>        -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232
>
> ...

Answer (score 7):

This is a crash due to stack overflow, see the recurring sequences:

```
Foundation _writeJSONArray + 236
Foundation _writeJSONValue + 504
Foundation ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 100
CoreFoundation __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 90
CoreFoundation -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232
```

Looks like you are somewhere writing an array into a JSON structure and your code ends up in an endless loop.

Your own code isn't shown in the stack trace, since the stack trace got too large (stack overflow) and those frames got pushed out of the history.

Comment: hey... maybe it's an array that contains itself?

Comment: What really confuses me is that I don't do any write any JSON in my app. I only read JSON from a web service.

Comment: That this happens during `writing an array into a JSON structure` is a guess. Since these are iOS internal framework calls we don't know. You should check your reading code if something like that could happen and check 3rd party SDK code. Without further details everything is a wild assumption. The crash itself is clearly a stack overflow.