# App crashes on Apple LLVM 3.0 but works OK on LLVM GCC 4.2

Tags: iphone, c++, gcc, llvm

I have a very strange crash when using the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler.
So there is some code, that uses [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) to load assets and create the scene (I've excluded all my code and even then it crashes):

```
aiScene* ai_scene = const_cast<aiScene*>(aiImportFileFromMemory(fileBuf, fInfo.uncompressed_size, aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_MaxQuality, NULL));

delete ai_scene;
```

Here is the screenshot of the stack trace for GCC:

[image]

And here is for LLVM:

[image]

In LLVM version destructor is called twice (and probably that's why I've got a crash).

I should also mention that all destructor code is located in header file and crashes only on device (tested on iPod 4 and iPad 2).

Is it a bug in LLVM compiler (probably in generation of arm assembly) or did I miss something?

Edit:

in case someone has similar problem use `aiReleaseImport(scene)` instead of `delete scene;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to `delete` that pointer at all. Read the documentation. It clearly states that you should not attempt to free it in any way.

> If the call succeeds, the contents of the file are returned as a
>   pointer to an aiScene object. The returned data is intended to be
>   read-only, the importer keeps ownership of the data and will destroy
>   it upon destruction. If the import fails, NULL is returned. A
>   human-readable error description can be retrieved by calling
>   aiGetErrorString().

And in addition, the documentation explicitly states that it's read-only, so do *not* `const_cast` the `const` away.

Comment: as for the const_cast - this is deprecated code, and I will remove that soon (the scene is actually treated as const).

Comment: thank you for pointing me the right direction. you were right about the delete operator.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier, and it was quite rare because I go no responses (other than my own) to that problem [AppStore build crashes on launch on iPhone 3g and iPod Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552873/appstore-build-crashes-on-launch-on-iphone-3g-and-ipod-touch)

It'd crash only on iPhone 3g, and on an old iPod touch.