# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the function:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _smID = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_smID"]intValue];
        _link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_link"];        
        _trigger = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_trigger"];
        _status = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_status"];
        _expiration = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_expiration"]intValue];
        _timeFromRegistratio = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_timeFromRegistratio"]intValue];
        _timeFromSubsription = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_timeFromSubsription"]intValue];
        _timeFromLastOpening = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_timeFromLastOpening"]intValue];
        _timeToTrigger = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_timeToTrigger"]intValue];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I print the object before `return self;` . But when it returns to the calling line, the object is already gone. Here is the calling line:

```
 SMBase *oldMonkeySurvayRule = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:oldMonkeySurvayRuleData]retain];
```

I got this error:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x60000008
0x0449709b in objc_msgSend ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.
```

Here is the .h:

```
@interface SMBase : NSObject{
    NSString *_status;
    NSString *_trigger;
    int _expiration;
    int _timeFromRegistratio;
    int _timeFromSubsription;
    int _timeFromLastOpening;
    int _timeToTrigger;
    int _smID;
    NSString *_link;
}
@property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *link;
@property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *trigger;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int expiration;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromRegistratio;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromSubsription;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromLastOpening;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeToTrigger;
@property  (nonatomic,assign)int smID;
```

Isn't retain enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282428/whats-the-difference-between-kern-invalid-address-and-kern-protection-failure

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Feb/msg00404.html this is related your problem :)

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: i give u LINKS for solve your problem ,,, BTW your problem is new for mine ...so i can not put it as answer  but may be help u for find solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
self.link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_link"]; 
self.trigger= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_trigger"]; 
//etc
```

I had the same problem. This code helped for me. Object returned by `decodeObjectForKey:` method is autoreleasing. Assigning it to property will retain it.

Answer (score 0):

Method `decodeObjectForKey:` returns autoreleased object, so you need to retain it. Below find an example. Do this for all instance variables:

```
_link = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_link"] retain];
```

Comment: Maybe instead of retaining every variable, I'll just set somehow else the properties in the .h?

Comment: You mean define strong properties and then assign them? If yes it will work too.

Comment: Is this OK?
property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *link;
property  (nonatomic, strong) NSString *trigger;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int expiration;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromRegistratio;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromSubsription;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeFromLastOpening;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int timeToTrigger;
property  (nonatomic,assign)int smID;

Comment: Didn't help (I have only changed the properties)

Comment: Even though you've declared properties, you are still assigning to the ivars. You either need to retain, or go through your properties. e.g.:  self.link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_link"];

Comment: @darren, please put it as an answer so I could check it as correct.

Comment: @darren maybe you can direct me to some good and thorough memory management tutorial?

Comment: @Luda it is the good one https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html